# The number of ways to schedule six activities

Tags: statistics, permutations, combinations

I'm trying to review for Probabilities and Statistics and came upon this Question.

If one needs to schedule a job interview for someone who wants to teach at a school. For the day of the interview, I need to schedule six different activities for the candidite:

- Meet with the Vice President of the school
- Talk with the Teachers in the department
- Tour the area/campus
- Teach a lesson
- take a 15 min break
- take a 30 min break

How many unique schedules can I create if I can't schedule a break at the beginning nor end? Assuming I must schedule each of the six activities at least once.

---

Normally if the order didn't matter I would just say 6! but since the breaks can't be in the beginning or end, i'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Also count the schedules that are not allowed, to subtract them. How many begin with a break? How many end with it? Inclusion-exclusion.